# Unable to use load balancing in node js(Sail js framework)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, load-balancing, pm2

I am new in load balancing the app. I am using the `pm2` and `ngnix`. I am referring this article [How to load Balancing node.js apps using Nginx?](https://medium.com/@samanbaboli/how-to-load-balancing-nodejs-apps-using-nginx-a3b4ceb7c782) but I am stuck in following command `pm2 start server.js -f -- 444`.I am unable to create different ports to run the instance of app. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

is this block present in your domain nginx conf ?

```
upstream my_http_servers {
    server 127.0.0.1:444;      # httpServer1 listens to port 444
    server 127.0.0.1:445;      # httpServer2 listens to port 445
    server 127.0.0.1:446;      # httpServer3 listens to port 446
    server 127.0.0.1:447;      # httpServer4 listens to port 447
}
```